# How to update offscreen cell of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am having a UITableView in my application and I have customized it. Each cell contains a Imageview and a button. When I click on the button a downloading process will start and the button will be replaced with a UIProgressView. And once the download complete the progress view will be removed and again the button will be displayed with different status. It is working fine for a cell which is visible in the screen. But I can't update a cell which is offscreen once the download is complete. The progress view updating is working even if the cell is offscreen. But having issue when try to replace the progress view with the button.

Here is some of my code samples:

for updating, once the download is done,

```
//Creating custom cell with the Id value and upadting the cell
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btnId inSection:0]; //btnId is the id of the button clicked
UIMenuItemCell *cell = [(UIMenuItemCell *)[self.menuItemsPanel cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] retain];

//hiding the progressview
for (UIProgressView *currentProgress in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    if ([currentProgress isKindOfClass:[UIProgressView class]]) {
        currentProgress.hidden = YES;
        [cell.contentView reloadInputViews];
    }
}
for (UIButton *currentBtn in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    if ([currentBtn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        if (currentBtn) {
        //updating the button status here, once the download is complete
   }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

when Cell comes OnScreen,  cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called.

in that method, put a check

```
if(download completed) remove progress bar and add button.
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but i am also having some other processes in this method. So having some other issues. Anyway in which part should I add this one? cell == nil or in cell!= nill?

Comment: you will do this in cell!= nil part.